# Ubuntu boot problem, (with youtube link)

Tags: boot

Hello wise people of ask ubuntu. After installing Ubuntu I had to re-boot my pc, but then I ran into a problem. When I boot I get into the GRUB meny, I choose Ubuntu, since I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, but then my pc just re-boot again and I get the same GRUB meny. This ends up being a loop where I can't properly boot Ubuntu. Check YouTube video to see exactly what happened.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGwzHJgA9do

Additional information:
 - I've tried booting Ubuntu from a USB-stick and then installed and ran Boot-         Repair. Still the same result afterwards.
 - I first installed Ubuntu using a USB-stick and help from [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button)
 - This is my first encounter of Linux and Ubuntu, so don't be afraid to teach me stuff :)

Thank you in advance